# What should I use for decoding/converting audio from file or buffer using AVFoundation or CoreAudio?

Tags: ios, macos, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I want to decode audio from a buffer or audio file and write it to a buffer for playback (I don't want to route it directly to the hardware) on macOS and iOS. I want to be able to convert it to another format too if supported. What classes/services should I use from AVFoundation/CoreAudio API to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AVFoundation` has classes that can do all these things.

1. `AVAudioFile` for decoding audio from a file to PCM (`AVAudioPCMBuffer`).
2. `AVAudioConverter` for converting between formats
3. `AVAudioEngine` with an `AVAudioPlayerNode` that can play back `AVAudioPCMBuffer`s

You might insetad use `CoreAudio` and `AudioToolbox` if you need more control over latency, devices or if you run into bugs in `AVFoundation`.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on how to decode from an audio buffer (not from file) using AVFoundation?

Comment: `AVAudioConverter` can do that.